# No injectior signals and error codes

Tags: electrical, diesel, electronic-control-module, fuel-injection

On a Hyundai Accent CRDI 3 cylinders, there is no signal on the injectors wires during cranking but if the car is forced to start with other methods the injectors will start getting the signal and operates normally ( so their wiring is good ), the car shows no codes on the scanner, it had camshaft problem but it is gone now.
All injectors wires are connected directly to the ecu

what could be the reason ?

Comment: does the car use a cold start injector?

Comment: @Ben don't know what that is